# Is there a way to stop Docker deleting containers every time Visual Studio is closed on my Windows PC?

Tags: c#, windows, macos, visual-studio, docker

I have created an app, which uses Docker to create containers.  The app takes about 20-30 minutes to build the first time and then it is very quick thereafter.

On my MAC; containers are kept until they are deleted by me.  However, on my Windows PC; the containers are automatically deleted every time I close Visual Studio 2017.  Therefore I have to sit and wait for my solution to build each time I open the solution fresh on my Windows PC.

Is there a way to stop Docker deleting containers every time Visual Studio is closed on my Windows PC?

So far I have looked for a setting inside Docker desktop and inside Visual Studio/Options, however I cannot find it.  I have also Googled this.

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2019, under `Tools->Options` search for `Docker Compose` and then set the `Remove containers on project close` option to `False`. Click `OK` and you should be good.

[image: Option to change]